# same click event availalble in different classes

Tags: c#, winforms, class, handler

My plan is to devide GUI elements in one class and having a class where those GUI elements will be shown or put on mainform/usercontrol.
So what I have to do, when I want to use a click Handler in GUI elements but is original placed in mainform/usercontrol?
Or in other words: If its possible to provide the click eventHandler via paramter to GUI element class constructor, how I access it inside GUI elements or create a reference of it that can be used inside GUI elements?

Hope you understood what my primitive goal is.

**Addition:**
Since we are in same namespace is the following possible ? I found that in history and tried and it worked, but involved classes were a Usercontrol and its mainform ( 2 forms ).

```
class GUI Elements {
  public event Eventhandler ButtenClickedHandler;

  private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if ( this.ButtonClickedHandler != null ) this.ButtonClickedHandler( sender, e )
  }
}

class Example : Usercontrol/Form {
  ...

  GUI Elements gE = new GUI Elements()
  gE.ButtonClickedHandler += new EventHandler( ClickEventhandler )

  public void ClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
  ...
}
```

Just a good example that helps to understand the principal of how it must be done.

Comment: Can you add a Tag for the UI framework you are talking about like probably `winforms`, `wpf`, `asp.net` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When registering an event handler it does not have to be in the same class, you can use a method on some other object just fine.

Also note that the compiler should be able to convert the "method group", i.e. the name of a method, to a compatible delegate just fine without creating an EventHandler explicitly:

```
gE.ButtonClickedHandler += gE.ButtonClickHandler;
```

Or you can just forward the event in the local handler

```
public void ClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    => gE.ButtonClickHandler(sender, e)
```

Comment: I hope i was clear enough above. GUI Elements is only a class that have uses Drawing and Forms and other system classes to be able to create UI elements not a usercontrol as per definition in my question. I do not understand atm how the event MyFooEvent is been present and accessible in Example class.

Comment: @beg-inner That sounds odd. The common way to use winforms is to use the designer to create and design your form. Have separate model classes to model the behavior of whatever it is you are doing, and use code behind to glue it all together. I have no idea what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Just look at my additions I made. I thought it will work only as concept with mutliple forms. Guessing a form is only a class that have visuals beside its the same if its only a class and one form

Comment: @beg-inner updated the example, you just need to forward the method call. You can route events/method calls in just about any way you want, but you need an overall architecture to ensure all components does not need to depend on all other components.

Comment: i am not really familiar in total which code parts can be simplified as you do in your example which has same result as I do above. Please forgive I need to learn a lot. As long as the compiler result creates a functioning program I believe its not important in first instance to shorten code instead of having it readable for better understanding. Thank you anyway for the suggestion and answer !